# How to hunt down HTTP request?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, http, httprequest

Trying to optimize one web project.

It uses asp.net (webforms), bunch of jquery plugins and whatnot.

Problem: there's unnecessary HTTP request to `localhost/undefined` and that makes every request take ~1s longer than needed.

Question: is there any tactic to find guilty code?

Clue: `undefined` makes me think that there's JS involved.

Firebug log:

> GET /undefined HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:17817
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; lv; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115
>   Firefox/3.6
>   Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
>
>   Accept-Language: lv,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
>
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-13,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Keep-Alive: 115
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Referer: http://localhost:17817/Default.aspx

---

> if you right click a line in the code, it gives you a conditional breakpoint. Check the name of the variable that has the URL value, and set a condition when typeof URL === 'undefined' or url === 'undefined' and look at the stack

Just set breakproint at line 3400 (with no conditions). It does not go through there.

> 3397 ajax: function( s ) {
>   3398 // Extend the settings, but re-extend 's' so that it can be
>   3399 // checked again later (in the test suite, specifically)
>   3400 s = jQuery.extend(true, s, jQuery.extend(true, {}, jQuery.ajaxSettings, s));

---

Narrowed issue down a bit => commented out 1 ascx controller that renders some images and uses gallerific jquery plugin and magic request dissapeared.

---

Problem was with galleriffic plugin initialization. It couldn't find anchor and it's href for creating thumbnails when there were no images or something. It's cool now...

Comment: Can you let us know the specific initialization setting you had to fix? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @Frank hard to remember... too lazy to go through TFS history. I guess i created dummy anchor. Or hacked gallerific plugin itself (debugged through JS and commented/removed line that was looking for anchor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you been able to identify what JS code is initiating the request? If you are using Firebug it should give you a line of code in the console window which is invoking the AJAX request. In the event it's something like a $.post() with a code line in the jQuery library, you can navigate the callstack within the Firebug plugin to try and figure out where the initial JS call is being invoked.

Comment: At the moment - it seems that debugging JS with firebug is the way to go.

Comment: if you right click a line in the code, it gives you a conditional breakpoint. Check the name of the variable that has the URL value, and set a condition when typeof URL === 'undefined' or url === 'undefined' and look at the stack

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out the **[HTTP Watch](http://www.httpwatch.com/)**.